# Store the result of a function with loop in a variable

Tags: python, numpy

This is probably a very basic question, I have to store the results of a for loop in a variable, but somehow this does not seem to work:

```
import ystockquote
import numpy as np
```

I define a vector of stocks

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['OXLC','CG','NYMT', 'MMLP','CMFN','PNNT']), columns=['Ticker'])
```

I use a loop to get the dividends of these stocks:

```
def func1(df):
    for x in df['Ticker']:
        return ystockquote.get_dividend_per_share(x)
```

I store the result of the function in the variable "dividends", but for some reason in the variable dividends I only find the dividend of the first stock appearing in the vector:

```
dividends = func1(df)
print(dividends)
```

Does anyone understand why this happens?

Comment: Am i correct that your for loop runs only once? You see that return statement will exit your for loop right away.

Comment: damn, so the mistake is in the loop right ? how do I correct it ?

Comment: please check answer by @smarx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` returns immediately from the function. So the first iteration of your loop is happening, but as soon as you reach the `return` statement, it returns that value. One solution is to collect up your results in a list and then return that:

```
def func1(df):
    results = []
    for x in df['Ticker']:
        results.append(ystockquote.get_dividend_per_share(x))
    return results
```

For this simple of a loop, you might consider list comprehension instead:

```
def func1(df):
    return [ystockquote.get_divident_per_share(x) for x in df['Ticker']]
```